# How to add leading zeros to the result of a date difference calculation, using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, leading-zero

One of the charms of the moment.js library is the perfect way it deals with sometimes having 366 days in a year ;-) and the varying length of monthes.

So I have assembled the following piece of code:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

Date.getFormattedDateDiff = function(date1, date2) {
  var b = moment(date1),
      a = moment(date2),
      intervals = ['years','months','weeks','days','hours','minutes','seconds'],
      out = [];

  for(var i=0; i<intervals.length; i++){
      var diff = a.diff(b, intervals[i]);
      b.add(diff, intervals[i]);
      out.push('<div>' + diff + ' ' + intervals[i] + '</div><br/>');
  }
  return out.join(' ');
};

window.onload = function calculateInterval() {
   var start = moment("2013-09-04"),
       end   = moment();

   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML  
     = 'Time elapsed between "' + start.toISOString().split('T')[0]
     + '" and "' + end.toISOString().split('T')[0] + '":<br/><br/>' 
     + Date.getFormattedDateDiff(start, end);
}
</script>

<p><label id="output"></label></p>
```

A codepen [can be found here ...](https://codepen.io/piotr-linski/pen/dyOqxNP)

Probably you will immediately notice that I am missing the leading zeros in the result.
I have tried several formatting-efforts. But unfortunately, all of them don't seem to work.

Any suggestions how to get the leading zeros in the result, so 07 years instead of 7 years, etc. are highly appreciated.

Comment: 100+ years should also be padded with 0, i.e 0100?

Comment: no, that's not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple if statement to prepend a 0 will work -- `typeof` diff() value returns `number` and you need to convert to a string to manipulate.

```
Date.getFormattedDateDiff = function(date1, date2) {
  var b = moment(date1),
      a = moment(date2),
      intervals = ['years','months','weeks','days','hours','minutes','seconds'],
      out = [];

  for(var i=0; i<intervals.length; i++){
      var diff = a.diff(b, intervals[i]);
      b.add(diff, intervals[i]);
      if (diff.toString().length == 1) {
        diff = "0" + diff.toString();
      }
      out.push('<div>' + diff + ' ' + intervals[i] + '</div><br/>');
  }
  return out.join(' ');
};

window.onload = function calculateInterval() {
   var start = moment("2013-09-04"),
       end   = moment();

   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML  
     = 'Time elapsed between "' + start.toISOString().split('T')[0]
     + '" and "' + end.toISOString().split('T')[0] + '":<br/><br/>' 
     + Date.getFormattedDateDiff(start, end);
}
```

You can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726040/javascript-adding-zeros-to-the-beginning-of-a-string-max-length-4-chars) for some fantastic leading 0 methods.

Comment: Initially I was looking for a solution that makes use of something like moment(Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY'). However, your pragmatic solution works perfectly. So it's fine with me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately `moment(end).diff(start)` outputs the unix milliseconds as a number. `moment(value).format("YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")` formats it correctly to what you're looking for, but assumes you're entering a raw date in milliseconds and goes to (19)77-07-05 05:09:30 though my .format input is probably wrong

Answer (score 2):

In your case you should handle it manually, because you output raw numbers. One way to do this is to use method `padStart`

```js
diff.toString().padStart(2, '0')
```

But this won't work in older browsers, see https://caniuse.com/?search=padStart for browser support.

You could write something like this instead

```js
function getLeadingZeroNum(num) {
    return num < 10 ? '0' + num : num;
}

getLeadingZeroNum(4) // 04;
```

Comment: Didn't know about padStart()!